# Paste URL from clipboard to browser address bar using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, clipboard

I have the following problem:
There is a button, pressing on which some URL is copied to the clipboard. I want to go to that URL using **javascript+Protractor**. How can I do that?

I've tried to open a new tab using

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('t').keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform()
```

for further pasting the URL, but it doesn't work, no new tab is opened. Maybe there is a way to access data in the clipboard or something like that?

---

I'm using **Windows** 7, **chrome** browser.

---

[EDIT]: For now I'm using a walkaround: After clicking the button, which copies link to clipboard, one of the button's attributes get the needed link as a value, so I can save it and use in `browser.get()`. Still I feel like cheating a little, so I'll leave the question open for a while